# Multi dimensional array with smarty

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I am working on a PHP project and I am trying to export a multi dimensional array to Smarty.

Below is how my array is populated:

```
$array = array();
            while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $array[$myrow['BugID']][$myrow['id']]['BugID'] = $myrow['BugID'];
                $array[$myrow['BugID']][$myrow['id']]['DateSent'] = $myrow['DateSent'];
                $array[$myrow['BugID']][$myrow['id']]['FromAddress'] = $encryption->decrypt($myrow['FromAddress']);
                $array[$myrow['BugID']][$myrow['id']]['ToAddress'] = $encryption->decrypt($myrow['ToAddresss']);
                $array[$myrow['BugID']][$myrow['id']]['Message'] = $encryption->decrypt($myrow['Message']);
            }
            $smarty->assign("array", $array);
            $content = $smarty->fetch("message-list.tpl");
```

Below is my template file

```
<table class="tableDetails">
    <tr>
        <th>Date Sent</th>
        <th>Bug ID</th>
        <th>From Address</th>
        <th>To Address</th>
        <th>Message</th>
    </tr>
{foreach from=$array key=header item=table}
    <tr>
        <td>{$array.DateSent}</td>
        <td>{$array.DateSent}</td>
        <td>{$array.DateSent}</td>
        <td>{$array.DateSent}</td>
        <td>{$array.DateSent}</td>
    </tr>
{/foreach}
</table>

Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [BugID] => 2
                    [DateSent] => 2014-03-17 22:51:08
                    [FromAddress] => someone@example.com
                    [ToAddress] => 
                    [Message] => This is a test. 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [BugID] => 1
                    [DateSent] => 2014-03-15 00:04:03
                    [FromAddress] => someone@example.com
                    [ToAddress] => 
                    [Message] => This is a message from the bug administrator to the bug reporter
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [BugID] => 1
                    [DateSent] => 2014-03-15 00:03:17
                    [FromAddress] => someone@example.com
                    [ToAddress] => 
                    [Message] => This is the content of the message from the bug reporter to the administrator
                )

        )

)
```

At the moment nothing is being outputted in my table, except for the table headers, nothing from the actual array.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Please, read how smarty foreach works: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

You need to iterate the inner array of each "bug". See:

```
<?php
// index.php
require_once('smarty/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty();

$bugs = array();
$bugs[1][412]['BugID'] = 1;
$bugs[1][412]['DateSent'] = date("F jS, Y");
$bugs[1][412]['FromAddress'] = "foo@bar.com";
$bugs[1][412]['ToAddress'] = "bar@foo.com";
$bugs[1][412]['Message'] = "this is a test!";
$bugs[2][534]['BugID'] = 2;
$bugs[2][534]['DateSent'] = date("F jS, Y");
$bugs[2][534]['FromAddress'] = "test@test.com";
$bugs[2][534]['ToAddress'] = "tosh@tosh.com";
$bugs[2][534]['Message'] = "lorem ipsum!";

$smarty->assign('bugs', $bugs);

$smarty->display("index.tpl");
```

Template:

```
<table class="tableDetails">
    <tr>
        <th>Date Sent</th>
        <th>Bug ID</th>
        <th>From Address</th>
        <th>To Address</th>
        <th>Message</th>
    </tr>
{foreach from=$bugs key=parentID item=table}
    {foreach from=$table key=bugUID item=bug}
    <tr>
        <td>{$bug.DateSent}</td>
        <td>{$parentID}</td>
        <td>{$bug.FromAddress}</td>
        <td>{$bug.ToAddress}</td>
        <td>{$bug.Message}</td>
    </tr>
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
</table>
```

`$parentID` will be the primary bug ID (either "1" or "2"). `bugUID` is the inner ID (such as "412" or "534").

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: That wouldn't help me unfortunately. Its done that way so all the different IDs are assigned to an array with an index of the bugID value, doing this would change the structure and not work for my needs